# Spring Integration filter

Tags: spring, filter, spring-integration

in my program, there's request to an API and then  message in the incoming channel is stored to a file. My problem is I get some kind of error in my payload for some request. I want to store such error file in another directory. How can I add a filter expression, so that such payload is stored in another directory. My code is:

```
<int:chain input-channel="abcconnect">
        <int:filter id="errorout" expression="payload.containsKey('errorCode')"/>
        <file:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="apiResponseWriter" 
            directory="${error.path}"
            filename-generator-expression="'abc-' + T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis() + '.json'"
            delete-source-files="false" />
    </int:chain>
```

The error in the payload file is: `{"TwitterApi":{"errorCode":400,"errorMsg":"beginTime or endTime is later than now(1472041145)","success":false,"cost":11,"params":`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` lets the message to pass and go ahead in the flow if its predicate returns `true`. In your case it looks like messages with the `errorCode` should go down the flow.

So, I guess you have to negate the expression and also add `discard-channel` to let the `false` message to be send to different flow for analyze, processing or storing to a different file like your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Adding a discard channel helped.

Comment: I have another question too, related to spring. Can you help me?

Comment: OK. Just raise a new SO question and someone (or even me) can help you.